# Edit access on custom list

Tags: list, sharepoint-designer, permissions

I have created a custom list "A" and I have set the the item level permission as "Create items and edit items that were created by the user". Now I want to create an admin group that should be able to edit items in list "A". If I give "Full control" permission to admin group, it works but I want to know according to this situation what should be the correct permission level for admin group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom permission level named "*Generic Edit*" with "Add and Edit items" permissions.

Create a group called "{*Yourlistname*} Members" where you can include users and give this group "Read" rights across the site.

Go to the list and grant permissions directly by breaking the inheritance and apply *Generic Edit* permission level to the *Members* Group.

For list administrators , contribute access will work but if you wish to deny delete item rights to administrator, create a custom permission level once again named "*Generic List Moderator*" and give this permission directly to the admin users on this list.

Let us know if you have any other concerns on the same.